# Count Blank Lines from a file in C

Tags: c, file, file-handling, fseek

Is there a way to count the total number of blank lines in a file in C language. I have been trying and below is my code but it is not working.

```
void countLines(char *f1)
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen(f1,"r");
  int d=fgetc(fp),count=0,countbl=0;
  while(d != EOF)
  {
    if(d=='\n')
    {
      d=fgetc(fp);
      if(d=='\n')
        countbl++;
      count++;
      fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR);
    }

    d=fgetc(fp);
  }
  printf("%d %d",count+1,countbl);
}
```

I am using fgetc to read the file charcater by charcater when fgetc encounters `\n` I check the next character if it is again  `\n` that means it is blank line but it is not working.

Sample Input

```
fileCount.txt(name of text file)
```

Contents of File

```
This is line one


Hello, welcome to programming

Code quotient - Get better at coding

b
```

Sample Output

```
8 4
```

Here 8 is the total number of lines and 4 is the total number of blank lines.

Here is the new code but still it is not working

```
void countLines(char *f1)
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen(f1,"r");
  int d=fgetc(fp),count=0,countbl=0,temp=0;
  while(d != EOF)
  {
    //printf("%c %c",temp ,d);
    if(d=='\n' && temp=='\n' )
      countbl++;
    if(d=='\n')
    count++;
    temp=d;

    d=fgetc(fp);
  }
  printf("%d %d",count+1,countbl);
}
```

Comment: What is the fseek for ?

Comment: The `fseek` is a cumbersome way of `ungetc`ing a character. Both are unnecessary if you keep the value of the previously read char (and initialize it to `'\n'`, so that a new-line character at the start counts as a blank line). Look backwards, not forwards here. After all, the `'\n'` is at the end of a line, yo you are interested in what you have seen already.

Comment: @John3136 in the first if condition, **d=fgetc(fp)** would shift the pointer to the next character, in order to move the pointer one step backward I have used fseek

Comment: @MOehm Could you tell me how fgets behaves when it encounters a blank line?

Comment: `fgets` doesn't encounter blank lines, it encounters single chars. You as programmer must determine whether there is a blank line. By the way, your definition of two consecutive new-lines is very narrow. A blank line could have spaces and tabs in it.

Comment: @MOehm will a line be considered blank if it has spaces and tabs?

Comment: Well, lines that have only spaces in them look like blank lines to me, but whather your program should consider them blank or not depends on your task.

Comment: @MOehm check the new code, still not working

Comment: Please, instead of saying "not working", make an effort to describe what is not working. Which errors do you get? Where does your actual output difer from the intended output?

Comment: @MOehm According to the new code it should count blank lines but it seems that  this **if(d=='\n' && temp=='\n' )** condition never gets fulfilled and as a result **countnl** remains zero

Comment: Why do you think that? If you have empty, your new code should work, except that ypou print `count + 1` instead of just `count`.

Comment: @MOehm It's not working `countnl` remains zero and I have added 1 to `count` because `EOF` will be reached at the last line and it will not be counted but I have to count the total number of lines also.

Comment: Are your lines really blank, that is have a length of zero? Could you please check that in an editor? I've also posted an answer below, which takes care of blank, but not empty lines. You could also try that if you like.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's define a structure to hold the line statistics, so that we can return t from the function:

```
struct linestat {
    size_t total;
    size_t blank;
};
```

Next, let's define what consitutes a blank line. Your definition of two consecutive newline characters it okay, but rather narrow, so let's say that a blank line consists of only space characters and it is terminated by a newline character. You can determine whether a character `c` is whitespace or not with the function `isspace(c)` from `<ctype.h>`.

You can go about this in different ways. Here's one way:

Scan a line until a newline character is seen and keep track of whether you encounter non-spaces on your way. Recoed that line in your stats. repeat. You must also check whether you encounter `EOF`'s, of course:

```
struct linestat count_lines(const char *filename)
{
    struct linestat ls = {0, 0};
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp == 0) return ls;

    while (1) {
        int blank = 1;
        int c = fgetc(fp);

        while (c != EOF && c != '\n') {
            if (isspace(c) == 0) blank = 0;

            c = fgetc(fp);
        }

        if (c == EOF) break;

        ls.total++;
        if (blank) ls.blank++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return ls;
}
```

Notes:

- The algorithm keeps track of what it sees on the way, so that you never have to jump backwards in the file. (Occasionally, it may be useful to do that and make a single character unread. In such cases, `ungetc` is better than `fseek`ing.)
- I've chosen to use `while (1)` with a `break` here, because I think it matches how the procedure works better. Note that the final line of a file will not be considered if it isn't properly terminated with a newline character.
- You should catch the case where the given file cannot be opened for reading. Once you have `fopen`ed a file, you must make sure to `fclose` it later.

Answer (score 0):

So I came with this new code, instead of counting blank lines what I did is count the total number of lines and the total number of filled lines and then subtracted filled lines from total lines and it works perfectly I don't know why earlier code was not working which was suggested by @MOehm may be due to compiler issue or I don't know.

Here is the code

```
void countLines(char *f1)
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen(f1,"r");
  int count=0,countbl=0;
  char str[200],*c1;
  c1=fgets(str,200,fp);
  while(c1 != NULL)
  {
    if(c1[0]>=32 && c1[0]<=127)
    countbl++;
    c1=fgets(str,200,fp);
    count++;
  }
  printf(" %d %d",count,count-countbl);
}
```